# Netsuite Invoice Line Item not adding

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

My Restlet should either add or update an invoice with the line items. The add bit works - invoice + line items, but the update doesn't appear to add a new line item. Code looks like this:

```js
update_record = nlapiLoadRecord('invoice', invoice_id)
var itemcount = update_record.getLineItemCount('item');
for (var i = 0; itemcount != null && i < itemcount; i++) {

 if (jsonobject.item[i].item) {
 
  update_record.setLineItemValue('item', 'item', i + 1, jsonobject.item[i].item)
  
 }
}
var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(update_record, true);
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'id = ', id)
return id;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `setLineItemValue`, try using the series of `selectLineItem`, `setCurrentLineItemValue`, and `commitLineItem` methods. `setLineItemValue` is not supported in all scenarios or on all fields.

See the NS Help article titled `nlobjRecord` for details on all of these methods.

Comment: I was able to use insertLineItem and setCurrentLineItemValue to get it working. Thanks.